# How to delete recorded position of mesh on animation timeline?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I've got problem with my animation. I've got a sword in my scene, but I somehow animated it so that its handle starts falling down when I play through the timeline, and I don't know how to delete this.

[image: .]
Look at the picture, there's some orange line at timeline bar - that's what I want delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the handle as a [rigid body](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Sergof/GSoC2012/Documentation). The yellow line in the timeline shows you how much of the physics Simulation is cached. To delete the rigid body and all of the motion calculated from it Select the handle, then in the *physics* tab of the tool bar press remove.
[image: physics tab]
You can also get to the physics settings in the *physics* tab of the properties window.  [image: properties window]

Answer (score 0):

Select the frame where the line, called a keyframe, is(the name of the object, in the bottom left corner, will become yellow) and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.